# How to filter/select on intermediate (pivot) table columns in Laravel (5.4)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

How do I create a column just in a pivot (intermediate) table in Laravel (5.4) and then filter results on it?

I have two models, Films and CastAndCrew. CastAndCrew are the various directors, producers, actors who work on a film. The pivot table should define the type of relationship between a CastAndCrew member and a Film. Obviously it's possible for someone to be e.g. an actor in one film and a producer on another, so I can't define this in their entry in the CastAndCrew table because it'll only be true for one film, and may be different for other films they worked on. So I assume I have to define the relationship in a pivot table, but I'm not sure how to do this exactly. What I've got so far:

```
class Film extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('filmtitle', 'description');

    public function List_Directors()
        {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CastAndCrew')->withPivot('type')->wherePivot('type', 'director');
        }

    public function List_Actors()
        {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CastAndCrew')->withPivot('type')->wherePivot('type', 'actor');
        }
}
```

and

```
class CastAndCrew extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname');

    public function List_Films_With_Director()
        {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Film')->withPivot('type')->wherePivot('type', 'director');
        }

    public function List_Films_With_Actor()
        {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Film')->withPivot('type')->wherePivot('type', 'actor');
        }
}
```

When new CastAndCrew members get added to the site, I'm intending to use the attach method, e.g. to add a new director:

```
$newcastcrew->CastAndCrew::create(['firstname' => Request::get('firstname'), 'lastname' => Request::get('lastname')]);

$newcastcrew->List_Films_With_Director()->attach($filmID, ['type' => 'director']);
```

1.) Is that right?

2.) Does the `->withPivot('type')` create the 'type' column in the Pivot table? If not, where/how do I define it?

2.) Presumably the `->wherePivot('type', 'director')` clause in `Film->List_Directors()` then returns CastAndCrew members who are directors of that film? (which is what I want)

Corrections much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: all thing it's ok you don't have any problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea and logic is perfectly fine. You might want to add a relationship without the type condition to fetch all the films of user and all the cast and crew of a film. You also need to name your methods and relationships better. I've cleaned up the code for you. Feel free to use this if you prefer.

```
class Film extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('filmtitle', 'description');

    public function castAndCrew()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CastAndCrew')->withPivot('type');
    }

    public function directors()
    {
        return $this->castAndCrew()->wherePivot('type', 'director');
    }

    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->castAndCrew()->wherePivot('type', 'actor');
    }
}

class CastAndCrew extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname');

    public function films()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Film')->withPivot('type');
    }

    public function filmsAsDirector()
    {
        return $this->films()->wherePivot('type', 'director');
    }

    public function filmsAsActor()
    {
        return $this->films()->wherePivot('type', 'actor');
    }
}
```